# Collection of scary children 's stories- Ember escapes a fire

Tags: short-stories, story-identification

I remember a hardback collection of children 's scary stories that I had in the 1980's. The stories may have had European roots. One story I remember in particular was about an ember that escaped a fireplace and went about causing mischief.

I would love to find this book of stories again!